# Japanese Double Byte Unicode Title Tag

Tags: unicode, seo, title, string-length

I understand that Japanese characters are Unicode and that they are double byte, so does this mean, for an optimal SEO title tag for my Japanese website, I should use 70/2 = 35 characters instead of the usual 70 characters or are Japanese characters treated the same way as normal ASCII characters? Does this also apply for description meta?

Comment: I think the 70 characters length is based on visual space used, not on actual bytes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, which is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, should I be posting questions like these under SEO stack exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese characters occupy different numbers of bytes depending on encoding and character. Each character still counts as one character.

There is no fixed upper limit on `title` element content length, though various recommendations have been made in different documents. E.g., HTML 2.0 recommended that titles should be fewer than 64 characters. [Google instructions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624) do not specify any specific limit, just this: “avoid unnecessarily long or verbose titles, which are likely to get truncated when they show up in the search results”.

Similar considerations apply to descriptions in `meta` tags.